# Deployment of a PyTorch computer vision deep learning model into a windows desktop app

Tags: python, windows, deep-learning, pytorch

I have trained a yolov3 model in PyTorch with my dataset and I also have written some utility codes for it that run alongside the model all in python language. Now I want to deploy this model and my utilities into a windows desktop app that takes a video and runs the model on its frames. How can I do this task with minimum change in my code or rewrite it in another language? What framework is the best option for designing the UI of the app?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I would first use your model with PyTorch to detect each frame and use numpy ImageDraw to draw around your object(to be detected). Here is an article on this: [Drawing a rectangle inside a 2D numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638790/drawing-a-rectangle-inside-a-2d-numpy-array)
2. Then I would use OpenCV(cv2) to append all the frames together to make a video you could also use ffmpeg. Here is a article on this(OpenCV): [How to make a movie out of images in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44947505/how-to-make-a-movie-out-of-images-in-python)
3. Then for your UI framework you could use PyQt5 to display your video: [Load an opencv video frame by frame using PyQT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303008/load-an-opencv-video-frame-by-frame-using-pyqt). But you could also use Kivy with Gstreamer: [Kivy VideoPlayer fullscreen, loop, and hide controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877267/kivy-videoplayer-fullscreen-loop-and-hide-controls)
4. Finally to turn your .py file into a .exe(executable for windows) I would use PyInstaller for that: http://www.pyinstaller.org/

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have already done steps 1 and 2, as this going to be commercial software in the end, does PyQt5 have good compatibility with windows? Also, as far as I know, Pyinstaller packages all the libraries in one .exe file, however I want to have a traditional setup.exe file and be able to lock or license the app in future. Will I be able to to that with Pyinstaller?

Comment: @Behnamkvl 1. For licencing software there is 'Cryptolens': https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3twJVAz-iI however it is not a free service. But say you wanted to make your licencing application yourself for free check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IArt2Fgv644 but I wouldnt recommend it as it's lengthy and you would need things like a server with a static ip and it would probably cost the same ammount as Cryptolens account.

Comment: @Behnamkvl 2. For turning your .exe into a setup.exe for users to install and uninstall easily, I would recommend to use something like 'NSIS':https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZX5kH72Yx4 @ 5:30 or you could use Inno: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KRMs9z6KoEU I believe there both free but just double check.

Comment: @Behnamkvl 3. For PyQt5 compatibility it works amazingly with windows but it it based on the Qt framework. I also believe that PyQt5 works on Linux and macOS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846501/how-to-install-pyqt5-on-windows